# Django swagger special character escape documentation

Tags: django, escaping, swagger, docstring

I use django and swagger. I write doc string in my django function like this :

```
/?first_name__icontains=saeed&age__gte=20.
```

But swagger show them like this

[image]

how can I escape characters like & in django and swagger?

Edit:

My code in docstring of a django view
[image]

Result in Swagger
[image]

Comment: Where exactly is this string used in your code? Please post your code. Can you also post a larger screenshot of Swagger UI that shows that string in context? The mode details the easier it will be for someone to help you.

Comment: I update the question, thanks for your notice.

Comment: Sorry but there's still not enough details... From my understanding, it looks like you have a `description` with Markdown markup and that line is supposed to be formatted as a code (using 4-space indent) but Swagger UI renders the line incorrectly. Is this what your question is about?

Comment: I type & in my doc string but swagger show &amp;. I think & is a special character in swagger but I don't know how to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` being rendered as `&amp;` in code blocks is a bug in Swagger UI 2.x which was fixed in UI 3.3.0:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2700

You need to update your Swagger UI version.

Comment: I use django rest swagger, what can I do for that?

Comment: @SaeedBabashahi Try the latest version of django-rest-swagger ([2.2.0](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/releases/tag/2.2.0)). It includes Swagger UI 3.x.

Comment: Thanks, I check it but it has a bug with JWT authorization.